# Sorting an array in-place in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.11, scala-generics

I tried this:

```
implicit class ArrayExtensions[A](a: Array[A]) {
  /**
   * Sort a slice [from, until) of this array
   */
  def sort(from: Int, until: Int)(implicit cmp: Ordering[A]) = java.util.Arrays.sort(a, from, until, cmp)
}
```

But, I think I am hitting [a bug in the compiler](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5783):

```
[error]  found   : Array[A]
[error]  required: Array[? with Object]
[error] Note: A >: ? with Object, but class Array is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: ? with Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]     def sort(from: Int, until: Int)(implicit cmp: Ordering[A]) = java.util.Arrays.sort(a, from, until, cmp)
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: I think JVM can be a tag. I believe Java should not be a tag.

Comment: What is the problem with calling `java.util.Arrays.sort` directly?

Comment: @kostya: I just posted the compile error I get when I call `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: I mean, if you have `val a: Array[Int]`, you can just call `Arrays.sort(a, from, until)` and it will just work. Why do you want to introduce `ArrayExtensions`?

Comment: @Kostya: I have a custom comparator that I need to pass in since I not only have a `Array[Int]` but also another `Array[Foo]`.

Comment: There is no method in `java.util.Arrays` that allows you to sort `Array[Int]` using custom comparator. Even sorting algorithm that is used for primitive arrays and Object arrays is different. Just call different methods for sorting `Array[Int]` and `Array[Foo]`.

Comment: I managed to make it work by copying `scala.util.Sorting.quickSort` code, replacing `Array` with `mutable.IndexedSeq` in it, and sorting with `quicksort(a.view(from, until))`. See https://gist.github.com/kolmar/5b891c6058b16757525b I'm not sure why Scala doesn't provide any built-in `quickSort` method for sorting a mutable sequence in place.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is right there in the bug you cited: "Java generic array cannot be used with Scala value types".  As the bug says, the real problem is that the error message isn't too helpful.  The problem is that you have no constraints on the type of A, but not all Scala types can be used as Java generic type parameters, only reference types can.  Try this:

```
implicit class ArrayExtensions[A <: AnyRef](a: Array[A]) {
    /**
     * Sort a slice [from, until) of this array
     */
    def sort(from: Int, until: Int)(implicit cmp: Ordering[A]) = java.util.Arrays.sort(a, from, until, cmp)
}
```

`AnyRef` corresponds to Java `Object`, while `Any` includes Scala types that are not Java objects (like `Int`).

Comment: For completeness link to Scala issue https://issues.scala-lang.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/si-5783. It's not bug per se, just not enough clear error message.

Comment: @pathikrit it can't work for Array[Int] per definition. You are calling generic Java method, which is still generic in Java sense, i.e. only for Object sub-classes, which obviously int in Java isn't. On Scala side, the Java constraint is interpreted as being a sub-class of AnyRef, while AnyRef ~= Object, which again Scala Int isn't. Search for specialized annotation to have an special case for Int. See http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/

Answer (score 1):

So, far I have gotten around by doing this:

```
a.slice(from, until).sorted.copyToArray(a, from)
```

But, this is not ideal as it requires two extra traversals.